# Why is the last element in my CSS3 box-sizing too wide?

Tags: html, css

[LIVE EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/cereallarceny/pen/eHEmJ)

So I'm using [Chris Coyier's CSS3 box-sizing grid setup](http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/).  And I've got my grids set up perfect.  Inside of each module I have a `div` which will set the background to be a CSS3 RGBA linear-gradient.  All is well and shows up fine, but the since I'm using `padding`, the background of the last element is taking up the width of the module **plus the** `padding`.  If you check out the example that might explain it further, the last module is the troubled one.  I've tried to reset last element to `padding-right: 30px` which forms the correct width but then it's not spaced out 100% over the width of the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*note this answer has multiple edits to reflect the evolution of the problem and needs*

You're telling the browser each element is 25% of the available width, then you are telling it to deduct 30px from the right of each element to space them out with. Then you are telling it "except for the last one, don't deduct anything from the right" so the first 3 are really 25%-30px, and the last one is the only one that is truly 25%.

How to resolve this is going to depend on what you want in your final layout, but I would get rid of the bit that says the last item has right-padding of 0px, and set all the elements to have left-padding of 15px and right-padding of 15px.

**EDIT1**

After clarifying needs, this answer suits OP better: http://jsfiddle.net/Az3eH/

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="tan-trans">
      1/4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="tan-trans">
      1/4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="tan-trans">
      1/4
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1-4">
    <div class="tan-trans">
      1/4
    </div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.tan-trans {
    background: #282816;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40,40,38,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(40,40,38,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40,40,38,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40,40,38,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(40,40,38,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(40,40,38,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#282826', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
}
.grid:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[class*='col-']{float:left;padding-left:1%;padding-right:1%; padding-top: 30px; }

.col-1-1 { width: 100%; }
.col-1-3 { width: 33.33%; }
.col-2-3 { width: 66.66%; }
.col-1-2 { width: 50%; }
.col-1-4 { width: 25.5%; }
.col-1-8 { width: 12.5%; }
.col-3-8 { width: 37.5%; }
.col-5-8 { width: 62.5%; }
.col-7-8 { width: 87.5%; }
.col-1-16 { width: 6.25%; }
.col-3-16 { width: 18.75%; }
.col-5-16 { width: 31.25%; }
.col-7-16 { width: 43.75%; }
.col-9-16 { width: 56.25%; }
.col-11-16 { width: 68.75%; }
.col-13-16 { width: 81.25%; }
.col-15-16 { width: 93.75%; }
[class*='col-']:first-of-type {padding-left:0; padding-right: 1%; width: 24.5%}
[class*='col-']:last-of-type { padding-left: 1%; padding-right:0;width: 24.5%}​
```

**Edit 2**
Upon further inquiry with OP, it appears that specifically what he needs (mixed percentage and fixed widths that would add up to 100% of the available width with variable numbers of columns and sizes) isn't really possible with a pure HTML/CSS solution. With this in mind, it is my opinion that he go with a fixed layout as per [960.gs](http://960.gs) which would allow better options in figuring out what width each percent should be. i.e: 100% == 960px and all subdivisions be a fixed width fraction of that.

Comment: That's better, but not exactly correct.  After that I have a left and a right padding of 15px, which is not correct.

Comment: The modules need to touch both sides spanning 100% of the width of the container.

Comment: yeah, that gets a bit trickier. You will need to have the inner two tabs be slightly larger than the outer, and you have to measure both the tabs and the gaps as either % or integers, can't mix. This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/Az3eH/

Comment: Not a bad solution, but this depends on setting the width for the first and last of their type which I couldn't predict for.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, CSS applies first and last, you don't need to predict it.

Comment: You apply `width: 24.5%` to the first and last of type.  Notice that I have other column sizes... they won't always be 1/4 of the width per module.

Comment: ah, I see; so instead maybe you can add more specific first and last selectors like `.col-1-3:first-of-type{...} .col-1-4:first-of-type{...} .col-1-8:first-of-type{...}`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16325/discussion-between-cereallarceny-and-invertedspear)

Comment: Ahh, but here likes the fatal problem: we won't always know what combination of module width we'll be using.  You could have a 1/4 then a 1/8 then a 3/8 for instance.  Since we're having such a long conversation about this... I feel there's a better way to do this.  Rather than fix my solution repeatedly, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you want, If I were doing this, I would work in fixed widths and design to a specific page width (960 is a commonly accepted standard page width, http://960.gs/). Like what they do here: http://drupal.org/ Their layout can stay fixed but still have all the widths and gutters they want. Because 100% == 960px in their layout, they can easily deal with fixed numbers when dividing out their widths.

Comment: You offer a good point.  I considered fixed widths, but I also know the client is not interested in doing a responsive website at any point in the project.  If they were, then it'd be reasonably difficult to implement with fixed width modules.  If you change your answer to reflect these comments then I'll mark it correct.  Thanks so much for your help and general advice.